# Parse XML feed every hour and store the new items in the DB

Tags: php, xml, rss-reader, feed

I'm building a news aggregator app. I want to parse an XML feed every hour and then store the new items in the database. The problem is that how do I parse only the new items in the news feed and do it every hour. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you not tried anything yourself yet? If yes, provide a [mcve], if no, then go ahead and try for yourself first.

Comment: you can take a look into Cron Jobs, scripts which execute after a specified time.

Comment: do each of the items in the xml feed have an associated datetime?

Comment: @RamRaider I want to parse feeds from techcrunch, gizmodo, lifehacker,  BBC, etc.

Comment: Each of the `item` nodes has a child `pubDate` - surely you should be able to use that by comparing to last timestamp for that feed in your db